# Multiple std::string temporaries resulting in the same c_str pointer

Tags: c++, stdstring, temporary

I have a function that returns a `std::string`. I'm passing that to `printf` and created a helper function that calls the function with common arguments and returns the c string pointer within the `std::string`. I'm getting the same pointer back for each call. I think it has something to do with temporary lifetime. I'd like to fix this and make it safe, if possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

std::string intToString(int num) {
  char buf[100];
  snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", num);
  return buf;
}

const char *helper(int num, int increment) {
  return intToString((num + increment) * 10).c_str();
}

int main() {
  for (int i=1; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("- %d: %3s  %3s  %3s  %3s\n", i,
           intToString((i + 0) * 10).c_str(),
           intToString((i + 1) * 10).c_str(),
           intToString((i + 2) * 10).c_str(),
           intToString((i + 3) * 10).c_str()
           );
    printf("+ %d: %3s  %3s  %3s  %3s\n", i,
           helper(i, 0),
           helper(i, 1),
           helper(i, 2),
           helper(i, 3)
           );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
- 1:  10   20   30   40
+ 1:  10   10   10   10
- 2:  20   30   40   50
+ 2:  20   20   20   20
- 3:  30   40   50   60
+ 3:  30   30   30   30
- 4:  40   50   60   70
+ 4:  40   40   40   40
```

Comment: `return intToString((num + increment) * 10).c_str();` - the `std::string` backing that pointer is gone by the time the caller gets the address. Your program invokes undefined behavior. The lifetime of the temporary in the first case extends. In the second, the only temporary retained is a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of `c_str()` is only valid as long as the string object exists and is not modified. Returning it from a temporary like you do in `helper` is not correct. Return an `std::string` instead, and only use `c_str()` at the site where you actually need to use it as a c-string.

For reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the equivalent code using only c++ objects and streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

std::string helper(int num, int increment) {
  return std::to_string((num + increment) * 10);
}

int main() {
  for (int i=1; i < 5; i++) {
      std::cout << "- " << i 
      << ": " << std::setw(3) << std::to_string((i + 0) * 10)
      << "  " << std::setw(3) << std::to_string((i + 1) * 10)
      << "  " << std::setw(3) << std::to_string((i + 2) * 10)
      << "  " << std::setw(3) << std::to_string((i + 3) * 10)
      << '\n'; 

      std::cout << "+ " << i 
      << ": " << std::setw(3) << helper(i, 0)
      << "  " << std::setw(3) << helper(i, 1)
      << "  " << std::setw(3) << helper(i, 2)
      << "  " << std::setw(3) << helper(i, 3)
      << '\n'; 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
- 1:  10   20   30   40
+ 1:  10   20   30   40
- 2:  20   30   40   50
+ 2:  20   30   40   50
- 3:  30   40   50   60
+ 3:  30   40   50   60
- 4:  40   50   60   70
+ 4:  40   50   60   70
```